# I'm getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception and I don't know why. Can someone shed some light?

Tags: java, libgdx, collision-detection

This is my first time making a 2D game. The code is in Java.

I have a character that can shoot blasts at zombies, and this is how I have been dealing with the collision detection between the blasts and zombies.

I am getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception for the line: `blastIter.remove();`

Why is that?

```
Iterator<Rectangle> blastIter = blasts.iterator();
Iterator<Zombie> zombieIter;

while(blastIter.hasNext()) {
    Rectangle blast = blastIter.next();
    blast.x += 200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    if(blast.x > window.length) blastIter.remove();

    zombieIter = zombies.iterator();
    while(zombieIter.hasNext()) {
        Zombie zombie = zombieIter.next();
        if(zombie.overlaps(blast)) {
            zombie.removeHealth(5);
            blastIter.remove();
            if (zombie.isDead()) {
                zombiesSlain++;
                zombieIter.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As requested, here is the complete stack trace:

Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array.removeIndex(Array.java:231)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array$ArrayIterator.remove(Array.java:540)
    at com.test.drop.Drop.render(Drop.java:128)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:208)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)

Comment: What is the complete stack-trace?

Comment: You call blastIter.remove() twice if the blast is out of the window (line 3 of the loop) and overlapping a zombie... You should probably have a `continue` statement after the removal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having `blastIter.remove();` in the inner loop is problematic, since you might try to remove the same blast multiple times. In addition, you might remove the blast before ever getting to the inner loop, in which case the inner loop should be skipped.

I'd suggest adding a flag that would prevent a blast from being removed more than once :

```
while(blastIter.hasNext()) {
    Rectangle blast = blastIter.next();
    blast.x += 200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    boolean removed = false;
    if(blast.x + 16 > window.length) {
        blastIter.remove();
        removed = true;
    }
    zombieIter = zombies.iterator();
    while(zombieIter.hasNext() && !removed) {
        Zombie zombie = zombieIter.next();
        if(zombie.overlaps(blast)) {
            removed = true;
            zombie.removeHealth(5);
            blastIter.remove();
            if (zombie.isDead()) {
                zombiesSlain++;
                zombieIter.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that you may also have removed it here before getting into the inner loop: if(blast.x > window.length) blastIter.remove();

Comment: @Tarik If the comment is directed at Regnarg, post it under the question instead.

Comment: @Tarik yes, I noticed it when editing my answer with the corrrect code.

Comment: Well, I can only +1 you only once :-)

Comment: Thanks @Eran! I ended up adding a break statement after the innermost if statement so that the same blast would not be removed more than once :) Does what I did do essentially the same thing?